# django EmailMessage not work

Tags: python, django, email

Codes:

```
                email1 = EmailMessage(from_email='cc@outlook.com', to=['cc@outlook.com'])
                print "email1:", type(email1)
                email1.attach(title + '.pdf', pdf, 'application/pdf')
                try:
                        print "email........"
                        print email1.send(fail_silently=False)
                except Exception as e:
                        print "Exception when sending emails:", e
```

Output:

```
email1: <class 'django.core.mail.message.EmailMessage'>
email........
1
```

Settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "firstname.lastname@company.com"
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

No exception, no error information. but it can not send email. No idea why and how to debug

when I changed localhost to my hostname, the following error appeared:

```
Exception when sending emails: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Thanks

Comment: You settings config for emailing?

Comment: Hmm.. shouldn't you use the outlook.com smtp server and appropriate port (smtp.live.com, 587)

Comment: Why no error messages? In fact, I need to send to our clients' emails from our company's email. outlook email here just for debug. The example here is so easy, but my code not work

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that from your localhost like that. I tried the same thing before. In shell, It didn't give any error and returns 1 every time which is successfull. But I couldn't send any email. Then I changed my email backend to amazon ses(simple email service) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow less secure apps, you can do it by click below link

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

also try this one

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

if still not works try changing password for gmail

`settings.py` should be

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-acount@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-gmail-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```